# Zendesk report overview API end point

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

Which API end point can be used to get the Reports Overview data?

I need to have the following data :

1. New Tickets
2. Solved Tickets
3. Open Tickets
4. Unresolved Tickets
5. Recently updated tickets

6.Pending Tickets

Also, I would like to pull a leader board of agents by their solved ticket counts and to have an individual report for each agent which shows the above 6 metrics only for the agent.

Answer (score 0):

The view preview count API can be used for your main ones. https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/views#preview-count

You can do a lot with the other view APIs, and if you don't want to create the view you use previews. Should you need more detail, your fallback is the /tickets.json endpoint to get all the data.